# Aplicar funções de validação em forma de cascata

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema e quero fazer validações através de funções.

Eu tenho a função `checkUsername` que faz consulta no banco para me retornar se pode ou não registrar com aquele username.

E depois tem outras funções para checar outras coisas como `checkEmail`. Como aplicar estas funções uma após a outra num submit do formulário?

Exemplos de funções que estou usando:

```
function checkUsername(username){
    $("#username").focusout(function() {        
        var username    = $("#username").val();
        var pattern     = /^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$/;
    if (pattern.test(username)) {
         var Urlverificadora = 'action=verificar_username&username='+username;
         $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            data : Urlverificadora,
            url  : painel+'checkUser.php',
            success: function(responseText){ // Get the result and asign to each cases
                if(responseText == 0){  
                    $("#username").css("border", "2px dashed green");
                } else if(responseText > 0){
                    $("#username").css("border", "2px dashed red");
                } else{
                    alert('Entre em contato com o administrador.');
                } //success
            }
        }); //ajax
    } else {
        $("#username").css("border", "2px dashed red");
    };}
)};
```

Comment: Interessante sua pergunta, você pode controlar o submit como disable até que todas as validações estejam corretas. No caso específico do usuário, seria bom se você escutasse as mudanças através de um evento. Assim,  o usuário já saberia se está com o nome de usuário certo antes de submeter o formulário.

Comment: #Ronny Amanrante (@Ronny Amanrante), você poderia demonstrar isso em código para que eu saiba como estruturar as validações e como chamar o script através do submit? Visto que existe funções, não sei aplicá-las em forma de cascata!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Vejo duas opções:

### Fazer a validação syncrona

Pode usar a opção `async: false` do jQuery para forçar o código a "ficar à espera" da resposta de validação de cada uma das suas funções. Apesar de apresentar esta opção primeiro não recomendo pois se a chamada ajax demorar o seu código fica "pendurado" e o utilizador nem percebe o que se passa.

Exemplo:

```
$.ajax({ url: "ficheiro.php", 
        data: {data: dados}, 
        async: false,
        // etc
```

### Fazer submit retardado via javascript

Você pode parar a submissão da `form` assim:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // talve seja bom criar aqui um overlay que indica que está a ser processado
```

e neste momento do código correr as suas funções para validação. Uma vez que tem várias e as respostas vão chegar em momentos diferentes pode guardar uma variável com as repostas todas. Uma array de booleans, ou uma variavel de incrementação, ou outro. Depois pode ter um setInverval que vai verificando se as respostas já chegaram. Ou ainda, pode encadear essas funções de validação para disparar uma em seguida da outra, de dentro da função success.

De qualquer maneira, quando as condições estiverem reunidas, e **para retomar o submit**, pode fazer assim:

```
$('form').off('submit').submit();
```

Isto retira o oscultador de `submit`da form, e faz de seguida o submit defenitivo.

No caso de o submit (após validação aceite) for submetido também via AJAX, então só precisa de fazer nova chamada ajax com os dados da form em vez dessa ultima linha que escrevi em cima.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que sua validação deve ser feita, claro, tanto no front-end quanto no Back-end, então pode trabalhar na mudança de foco do campo.

```
$("#username").blur(function(){
    if(checkUsername($(this).val()){
        $("#username").attr("class","invalido");
    }
}):
```

e também pode trabalhar com o submit do formulário.

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    $("input").each(function(){
        if($(this).is("#username")){
            if(checkUsername($(this).val()){
                $("#username").attr("class","invalido");
                return false;
            }
            if(checkEmail($(this).val()){
                $("#email").attr("class","invalido");
                return false;
            }
            if(checkPassword($(this).val()){
                $("#password").attr("class","invalido");
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}):
```

Comment: Para que isto funcione, você terá que alterar o AJAX para síncrono (`async: false`) e modificar uma variável dentro do calback do success para retornar o valor boleano.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode controlar a chamada de suas funções na função `.submit()` do jQuery:

```
$( '#send_form' ).submit(function(){ 
   //aqui você poderia adicionar suas funções validadoras. 
   if( name == false ){
      return false; // Caso a var name esteja como false ele não envia o form.
   }
});
```

E no caso do seu AJAX recomendo que você controle através do `.change()`:

```
$( '#username' ).change(function(){
   //chamada ajax e controlador da chamada como adicionar borda ou etc..
});
```

Comment: Se você quiser que eu seja mais específico em algo, dê um toque aqui nos comments.

Comment: #Ronny Amarante, pode por favor me dar um exemplo de 2 validações, por exemplo, username e email juntas? Seria um "if else" para cada verificação e se no final houvesse pelo menos um "return false" o formulário não seria submetido? E como "separo" ou "junto" validação com função?

Comment: `if( name == false ){
      return false; // Caso a var name esteja como false ele não envia o form.
   } else if( email == false ){...}...`

Comment: Caso o submit receba um retorno false ele não irá enviar. E dependendo da quantidade você até poderia usar: `(x < 10 && y > 1)`. Dependendo do tamanho das validações e quantidade delas, eu usaria o [Revealing Module Pattern](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/)